# asp-classic with a javascript chart

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Consider the following JS Chart (taken from the free bootstrap getting started template)

```
   // Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';

// Area Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Mar 1", "Mar 2", "Mar 3", "Mar 4", "Mar 5", "Mar 6", "Mar 7", "Mar 8", "Mar 9", "Mar 10", "Mar 11", "Mar 12", "Mar 13"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Sessions",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointHitRadius: 50,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: [10000, 30162, 26263, 18394, 18287, 28682, 31274, 33259, 25849, 24159, 32651, 31984, 38451],
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 7
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 40000,
          maxTicksLimit: 5
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)",
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is pass an asp-variable to this chart, I naively thought that I could establish a sql-server connection as follows :

```vb
<%
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'  Declare variables
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim gobjConn
Dim gsConnect
Dim gsSQL

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'  Open database connection
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gsConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server ;Database=mydB;Uid=UserName;Pwd=myPW;"
Set gobjConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

gobjConn.Open gsConnect

gsSQL = "SELECT Sales, Week from Sales" 

%>
```

and i could pass Store & sales to the above Data Labels (x and y axis respectively) but adding any asp within my JS file causes the page not to load the chart.

any advise would be great.

happy to take another path, this is more for learning (limited to asp-classic at my place of employment)

Comment: Unsure why this was down-voted, if this is off-topic or not a valid question please let me know as I feel I've followed SO etiquette!

Comment: Your code doesn't attempt to query SQL Server it just opens `ADODB.Connection` and sets up a string variable containing a query, it doesn't execute it or do anything. This does not reflect a good [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Lankymart (and for your help in my last question with the JSON asp converter) I will edit my question to meet the MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing ASP code in a JS file isn't possible unless you add a custom handler mapping for .js files so they behave as .asp files. What you could do instead is generate the data in your parent asp page and assign the values as global javascript variables which can be read by your external charts JS file.

Untested, but something like this:

```
<%

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Declare variables
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim gobjConn
    Dim gobjRS
    Dim gsConnect
    Dim gsSQL
    Dim gsData
    Dim gsLoop
    Dim chartLabels
    Dim chartSales

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Open database connection
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    gsConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server ;Database=mydB;Uid=hal03df;Pwd=myPW;"
    Set gobjConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set gobjRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    gobjConn.Open(gsConnect)
    gobjRS.open "SELECT Sales, Week FROM Sales ORDER BY Week ASC",gobjConn

    ' check the recordset contains data

    if NOT gobjRS.EOF then

        ' convert the recordset to a 2d array

        gsData = gobjRS.getRows()

        ' loop through the recordset array

        for gsLoop = 0 to uBound(gsData,2)

            ' convert the week value to a date variable

            gsData(1,gsLoop) = cDate(gsData(1,gsLoop))

            ' build the chart labels

            chartLabels = chartLabels & """" &_ 
            MonthName(Month(gsData(1,gsLoop)),True) & " " & Day(gsData(1,gsLoop)) & """"

            ' build the sales labels

            chartSales = chartSales & gsData(0,gsLoop)

            ' add a trailing comma?

            if NOT gsLoop = uBound(gsData,2) then
                chartLabels = chartLabels & ", "
                chartSales = chartSales & ", "
            end if

        next

    else

        ' No sales data

    end if

    gobjRS.close
    gobjConn.close

    set gobjRS = nothing
    set gobjConn = nothing

%><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>


<script language="javascript">

    // assign the asp chartLabels/chartSales variables as global javascript arrays

    var chartLabels = [<%=chartLabels%>];
    var chartSales = [<%=chartSales%>];

</script>
<script language="javascript" src="path/to/charts/js/file"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A slight alternative would be to perform a group concat in your SQL, which would eliminate the need to loop through the recordset. Although my knowledge of SQL Server isn't great, so I wouldn't know how to do this offhand.

In your charts JS file:

```
<script language="javascript">

// Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';

// Area Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: chartLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Sessions",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointHitRadius: 50,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: chartSales
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 7
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 40000,
          maxTicksLimit: 5
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)",
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Adam my man! Thanks for this (and the full calendar page you helped with, it's a big hit) I will test this first thing tomorrow. This is the first Google result for asp classic java script chart BTW!

Comment: Almost have this working! i wanted to pass arbitrary week numbers that I have in my SQL dB (1-52) so I don't need to use the date functionality. To that end, I commented out the `cDate` with a ' and changed  chartLabel = `chartLabels = chartLabels & gsData(1,gsLoop)` however it's just loading up blank in my test env.

Comment: `chartLabels = chartLabels & """" & gsData(1,gsLoop) & """"` your chart JS file is most likely expecting the labels to be a string.

Comment: I'm unsure if it's me or perhaps the JS file, the two JS Variables call correctly (tried both as int & string) when I inspect with view source on my asp page. they populate as expected (both lists match in size), even when I added the JS code to my html, it populates within the actual label when I use the asp-variable <%=chartLabels%>` but the variable does not work.  in both instances the chart does not populate or show up.

Comment: @Datanovice Are you sure you're assigning the variables before you load the chart JS file? Javascript is sequential, so if you assign them after you load the chart JS file they will be undefined. Also, I noticed in your original code that you had a comma at the end of your datasets list that didn't need to be there (it should be `data: chartSales` not `data: chartSales,`). Try opening developer tools (F12) and see if any errors have been logged in the console.

Comment: Finally figured it out! it was just some slight formatting I messed up, took me many hours but I got it, thanks for the tip with the dev console, you taught me something new again. Consider me a life-long padawan! Thanks adam! I seriously owe you a coffee or three!